# Ubuntu taking way too long time to start

Tags: boot, gnome, startup, swap

So, I have a Dell laptop. Core i5 4th Generation and 8GB RAM. I recently installed Kali alongside Ubuntu and Windows 10 and then when I booted from Ubuntu (15.10 with Gnome) again it took a VERY LONG TIME to show up the log in interface, comparing to before I installed Kali, which'd take 20-30 tops(Before GRUB the speed was fine, it just takes to long with that little Gnome circle rolling). As a silly newbie I removed kali thinking it'd get better because I thought that the partition sequence was making the trouble (it was like sda1, sda2, sda3, sda4, sda5, sda8,sda6,sda7) but it didn't work. I looked it up but didn't find anything. Please  Help.

EDIT:
boot.log gave me this:

```
[K[    [31m*[1;31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e39e44ff\x2dbf9e\x2d4c0e\x2dbc35\x2dba255ac475e6.device (1min 29s / 1min 30s)
[K[     [31m*[0m] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e39e44ff\x2dbf9e\x2d4c0e\x2dbc35\x2dba255ac475e6.device (1min 30s / 1min 30s)
[K[[1;31m TIME [0m] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-e39e44ff\x2dbf9e\x2d4c0e\x2dbc35\x2dba255ac475e6.device.
[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/e39e44ff-bf9e-4c0e-bc35-ba255ac475e6.
[[1;33mDEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Swap.
```

Many  of the "A start job...", actually. Like fifty.

And my fstab looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=3504ff47-dec1-407c-ad0a-a82b74007d24 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=7ADE-45D6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=ab6e808f-2570-44d6-9552-5b90a55723a5 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=e39e44ff-bf9e-4c0e-bc35-ba255ac475e6 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=7ADE-45D6  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks, I didn't really know how to do it. haha. But I can only do it in 17 hours for some reason. Anyway, thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!!! The problem was that the UUID of swap on fstab was different from the actual UUID that is shown using: `sudo blkid.` I just had to replace it and boot is like a bullet again. :D